# i have a probleme in react proptypes.object.isRequired

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In this code when i write proptypes with camel case it shows me empty page and when i write it with upper case (PropTypes) it shows me : compiled with problems
Line 39:9:  Typo in static class property declaration

**CODE :**

```
Contact.PropTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Clean contact cards with no errors using data from the contacts component

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

React components use a special property named `propTypes` to set up type checking and then you need to use `PropTypes` to define the type

It should be like this:

```
Contact.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

And you need:

```
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
```